# Overlapping two GridLayout

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm making sort of "Othello Reversi Game", using Kivy/Python.
Basically, i have a GridLayout that represents a "Graphic Layout" for the Board itself. It is filled with "Tile" instances (that are just custom Labels using "ButtonBehaviour, and of course a "Label"), so i can click on them and perform certain actions. This is the code working just fine.

main.py

```
class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.create_grid()

    def create_grid(self):
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                tile = Tile(row, col)
                self.ids.board.add_widget(tile)


class Tile(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, row, col, **kwargs):
        self.row, self.col = row, col
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos, source='images/tile_3.png')

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Tile object in pos=({}, {})>'.format(self.row, self.col)

    def update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def on_press(self, value=None):
        print(self)
```

othello.kv

```
<Grid@GridLayout>:
    rows: 8
    cols: 8
    spacing: (2, 2)

    size_hint: None, None
    size: dp(400), dp(400)


<GameScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'

        AnchorLayout:
            Grid:
                id: board
                pos_hint: {'x': (box_layout.width - self.width) / (2 * box_layout.width)}
```

Output

[image]

What i'd like to do, is to make another GridLayout overllaping the previous one. It should have the same size of the other, but in this case, it will represent each piece used in the game. I have 3 images, which 2 of them are basically a piece with a transparent background, so that i can still see the below Tile, and another image that is fully transparent so that i can see the whole Tile (representing there's no piece in there). Unfortunally, i cannot figure out, how to properly make these 2 grids overlapping, or if there's another better way of doing this. I'm up for any kind of suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: There's not really need to provide and example. You can use a GridLayout filled with whatever you want, and another one overlapping the previous one. That's it.

Comment: Your question is: *I have tried this and I have a problem with this*, that implies that you think you have tried something and you have failed, and according to the SO rules you must provide a [mcve], can you do it?

Comment: cannot right now, not home, but i will.

Comment: okay, take your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved:

```
<GameScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        AnchorLayout:
            id: anchor_layout

            FloatLayout:
                Grid:
                    id: board
                    pos_hint: {'x': (anchor_layout.width - self.width) / (2 * anchor_layout.width), 'y': (anchor_layout.height - self.height) / (2 * anchor_layout.height)}

                Grid:
                    id: pieces
                    pos_hint: {'x': (anchor_layout.width - self.width) / (2 * anchor_layout.width), 'y': (anchor_layout.height - self.height) / (2 * anchor_layout.height)}
```